# Making a Icecast Playlist from the Console

Tags: ssh, audio, streaming

I got HP 6G RAM laptop that use as a home server, and a netbook that i use as my everyday console. I recently installed icecast server on the server as playing audio files on the netbook halts my system, so I use "Radio Tray" to receive the streaming from the server over my local home network and I dont compromise my netbook's performance. rightnow i would like to be able to make a playlist from the audio folders i have on the HP server through ssh. is there a simple way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps fapg + ezstream is the right toolchain for this job.

[fapg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/fapg.1.html) generates the playlist file in a format of your choosing from a list of folders containing audio files

[ezstream](http://www.icecast.org/ezstream.php) can take the playlist file and stream it to your icecast server.